# How to find hash code of a Collection?

Tags: java

To my understanding, the following code should print `HashCode` of collection, as i am printing its `HashCode` directly.

However, when I run the following code  i am getting `Stack overflow` error:

```
    public class Test1  {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        m1(new LinkedHashSet<Collection<?>>());
    }

    private static void m1(final Collection<Collection<?>> cl) {
        cl.add(cl);
        try {
            System.out.println(cl.hashCode());
        } catch (Error err) {
            System.out.println(err);
        }
    }

}
```

Can some one explain this behavior ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have created a `Collection` that contains itself as an element.

A `LinkedHashSet`'s `hashCode()` is a function of its elements' `hashCode`s (as you can see below), so computing the `hashCode()` leads to infinite recursion.

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = 0;
    Iterator<E> i = iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        E obj = i.next();
        if (obj != null)
            h += obj.hashCode(); // when obj == this, as in your case, this
                                 // call leads to infinite recursion
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: So we can not use self referential collection in java  ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @Joker Well, you can't use such a collection if you are going to use methods such as `equals` and `hashCode`, which call the same methods on each element of the collection.

Comment: @Joker, And this behavior mirrors the constraints on the usual mathematical objects called "sets", which inspire Java's `Set`s.  In the usual formulations of set theory, it can be *proven* that no set contains itself as an element.

Comment: @JohnBollinger--I don't think so it is specifically for set only, what i understand from Eran's explanation is when ever collection contains it self it will result in to this error.

Comment: @Joker I don't know if all Collections have this behavior (you can certainly implement a Collection of your own that doesn't have this behavior), but it makes sense for them to behave this way, since `hashCode` must be consistent with `equals`, and it makes sense that in order for two Collections to be equal to each other, each pair of corresponding elements must be equal to each other.

Comment: Here's the relevant link for lists: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#hashCode--

Comment: @Eran-- Sir, Let me verify for other collections as well , will share the results with here in comments itself.

Comment: @Joker I already checked that all Lists share this behavior (it is stated in the List Javadoc).

Answer (score 4):

It's caused by this line:

```
cl.add(cl);
```

You're adding the collection to itself. Since the hash code of the set is based on the elements contained in the set, the `hashCode()` method of `cl` will be called recursively.

From the [`AbstractSet.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSet.html#hashCode--) javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Returns the hash code value for this set. **The hash code of a set is
>   defined to be the sum of the hash codes of the elements in the set**,
>   where the hash code of a null element is defined to be zero. This
>   ensures that `s1.equals(s2)` implies that `s1.hashCode()==s2.hashCode()`
>   for any two sets `s1` and `s2`, as required by the general contract of
>   `Object.hashCode()`.